# how to clear html cache

Tags: html

I had a website which has some html files and they are always getting cached in browser. I added below lines but not working as expected

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" CONTENT="-1">
```

I tested in internet explorer 9 by enabling `cache-> always refresh from server` option and then it's fetching fresh copy of html from server but in other browser's like chrome and opera it's caching every time. Please let me know how to prevent this cache issue.

Regards,
Sukumar

Comment: Are these lines added to the HTML files you're serving, or are they turned into HTTP1.0 protocol header `Pragma: no-cache` and [HTTP1.1 protocol header `Cache-Control: no-cache`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13) by your server software?

Comment: i had put them in the server html file in <head> section(default.html)

Comment: Aha. Try using [wireshark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireshark) on your connection and see if the server is sending conflicting cache headers. Incidentally, why are you trying to defeat caching mechanisms with static files anyway? Seems like something else must be broken.

Comment: @sarnold ok. i'll try tomm and let you know. Here it's already 2:30 AM :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">

<META HTTP-EQUIV="EXPIRES" CONTENT="-1">
```

Check http://support.microsoft.com/kb/234067

Comment: It's good to use both Pragma and Cache-Control to prevent HTTP 1.1 non-compliant browsers from misinterpreting.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I had added this line but still no luck.

Comment: for me chrome and opera is driving crazy :(

Comment: i'll check tomm and let you know . Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you just doing it for testing or production?